# Get the Row values from a excel based on the column Value

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am trying to a get the Row values from a excel sheet, based on the column Value.
e.g. I have CutsomerID as lets say 5 , so I want First name 5, last Name 5 and Address 5

[image]

I am converting whole excel sheet into DataTable and then trying to read on each DataRow, when I get CustomerID as 5, I copy all the values and break from the loop
Here is my code and it is working fine as well, but I was wondering is there any way to optimise it.

Here is my Code.

```
public ExcelData GetDataByCustomerID(String excelFilePath, String customerID)    
{
   OleDbConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new  OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
   connectionStringBuilder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
   connectionStringBuilder.DataSource = excelFilePath;
   connectionStringBuilder.Add("Mode", "Read");

   const string extendedProperties = "Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES";
   connectionStringBuilder.Add("Extended Properties", extendedProperties);

   String connectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ToString();
   // Create connection object by using the preceding connection string.
   using( var objConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
   {
        objConn.Open();

        // Get the data table contaning the schema guid.
        DataTable excelSheetsDataTable = objConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        if (excelSheetsDataTable == null)
              return null;

        // get all the tables in the Sheet
        List<String> excelSheets = (from DataRow row in excelSheetsDataTable.Rows select row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString()).ToList();

          // Our data is on First sheet only
                OleDbCommand _oleCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [" + excelSheets[0] + "]", objConn);
                OleDbDataAdapter oleAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
                oleAdapter.SelectCommand = _oleCmdSelect;

                DataTable newDataTable = new DataTable();
                oleAdapter.FillSchema(newDataTable, SchemaType.Source);
                oleAdapter.Fill(newDataTable);

                if (newDataTable.Columns.Contains("CustomerID"))
                {
                    foreach (DataRow rowValue in newTB.Rows)
                    {
                        if ((string) rowValue["CustomerID"] == customerID)
                        {
                            var data = new ExcelData
                            {
                                customerFirstName = rowValue["Customer_First_ Name"].ToString(),
                                customerLastName = rowValue["Customer_Last_Name"].ToString(),
                                customerAddress = rowValue["Customer_Address"].ToString(),
                            };
                            return data;
                        }
                    }
                    String message = String.Format("The CustomerID {0} not found in Excel file {1}", customerID, excelFilePath);
                    MessageBox.Show(message);
                }
                else
                {
                    String message = String.Format("The Column CustomerID not found in Excel file {0}", excelFilePath);
                       MessageBox.Show(message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }


public class ExcelData
{
    public String customerID;
    public String customerFirstName;
    public String customerLastName;
    public String customerAddress;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just add a `where` clause to your `select` query

Comment: You could use a DataReader to read line by line

Answer (score 0):

Courtesy msdn web site:

Link: [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bf16a227-afc5-44a0-8f39-0976b61c0ff8/how-to-use-sql-query-having-where-clause-in-excel-sheet)

```
DataTable dt;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            string connectionString = string.Format("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source ={0};Extended Properties = Excel 8.0;", this.openFileDialog1.FileName);
            var con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            var cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from [sheet1$] where [MRN#]=@c", con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@c", "33264");
            con.Open();
            var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(dr);
            }
            dr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            DataGridView dv = new DataGridView();
            this.Controls.Add(dv);
            dv.DataSource = dt;
        }

    }
```

**EDIT:**
As per your code you should try the below lines of code:

```
OleDbCommand _oleCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [" + excelSheets[0] + "]" + " Where [CustomerID#] = @custID"  , objConn);
    _oleCmdSelect.Parameters.Add("@custID", customerID);
    OleDbDataAdapter oleAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    oleAdapter.SelectCommand = _oleCmdSelect;
```

Comment: I added this line  oleCmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("CustomerID",  customerID); but it gave error that OleDBCommand.Prepare metgod requied all parameters to have an explicitly set type

Comment: @Pankaj - modified the lines of code, as per your example above.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `select` query to like below -

`@"SELECT * FROM [" + excelSheets[0] + "] WHERE CustomerID=<your_value>"`

Comment: It gave an Error that Syntax Error (missing operator) in query expression 'CustomerID = <5>'.

Comment: Don't use those `<` `>` (angle brackets). They are just placeholders. Use `CustomerID=5`

Comment: Now It gave an error that System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: I guess, Default value for `HDR` in Excel oledb connections string is `No`. So you need to refer your columns with F1, F2,...So your where clause will be `F1=5`. If you add `HDR=Yes` in your connection string, you can use `CustomerID=5`

Comment: This is already there in my code, 
const string extendedProperties = "Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=YES";